# Cauchy Local Existence and Uniqueness using Implicit Function Theorem for Banach Spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, implicit-function-theorem, frechet-derivative, cauchy-problem

**Question**: I have the following function $$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F : \mathbb{R}\times \{\omega \in C^1([-1,1]) \ |\  \omega(0) = 0\} & \longrightarrow C^0([-1,1]) \\
 (\alpha, z) & \longmapsto \frac{dz}{d\tau} - \alpha f(\alpha \tau, z(\tau)+\xi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

With $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. How can I show it to be continuous in $(0,0)$?

**Context**: In my advaced analysis course we've introduced Fréchet differentiation on Banach Spaces and stated the implicit function theorem for Banach Spaces as follows:

> Given the Banach spaces X, Y, Z, the point  $(x_0, y_0) \in X \times Y$ and $U \subset X \times Y$ a nbhd of $(x_0,y_0)$, and an application $F: U \longrightarrow Z$ such that :
>    1) $F$ is continuous in ($x_0,y_0$)
>   2) $F(x_0,y_0) = 0$
>   3) $\exists F_y' (x,y)$ for each $(x,y) \in U$, the application
>   $$\begin{equation}
> \begin{split}
> F_y' : U &\longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(Y,Z) \\
>  (x,y) &\longmapsto F_y'(x,y)
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}$$
>   is continuous in $(x_0,y_0)$ and the operator $F_y'(x_0,y_0)$ is invertible.
>   Then there exist an open nbhd $I$ of $x_0$, an open nbhd $J$ of $y_0$ and a unique function $\phi: I \rightarrow J$ with $\phi(x_0) = y_0$ such that:
>   $$F(x,y) = 0 \quad (x,y) \in I \times J \iff y = \phi(x)$$

As an application of this theorem we've proved a "weak" version of the local existance and uniqueness theorem for the Cauchy problem:
$$\begin{cases} x' = f(t,x) \qquad f: \Omega \text{ open } \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f \in C^1(\Omega)\\ x(0) = \xi \end{cases}$$
and $t \in (0,1)$.
Given that we're searching for a solution $x: (-\alpha, \alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we do the variable change $z(\tau) = x(\alpha \tau) - \xi$ with $z:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and we get the equivalent problem:

$$\begin{cases} z' = \alpha f(\alpha \tau, z(\tau) + \xi) \\ z(0) = 0 \end{cases}$$

Then we've introduced the following function $$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F : \mathbb{R}\times \{\omega \in C^1([-1,1]) \ |\  \omega(0) = 0\} & \longrightarrow C^0([-1,1]) \\
 (\alpha, z) & \longmapsto \frac{dz}{d\tau} - \alpha f(\alpha \tau, z(\tau)+\xi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

A pretty straightforward application of the implicit function theorem for Banach spaces gives the result. What bothers me is that we've not proved that $F$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ (we've not even mentioned it), and it does not seem so trivial to me. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so the only question is whether that map $F$ is continuous. (Next time, if you want, try to get faster to the question, and then you can add all the context you want).

Comment: Yeah, the fact is that I initially had other questions about this solution but as I was writing it, I solved them lol